# Can Qualcomm Quick Charge Charger Charge 3 18650 cells in series

Tags: voltage-regulator

Please may I ask : can quick charge charger charge batteries in series ? Say 3 series of 18650 batteries giving about 12.6 volts; can your quick charge adapter charge it just putting it in series ?

Thank you

Comment: I find it difficult to quickly pronounce your question: "can quick charge charger charge..."! :-)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Questions on the usage of electronic devices are off-topic. Look up the manual of your charger, what's written in it?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, QCC isn't designed for that, it is designed for the typical case where a phone has a single cell battery (so about 3.6 V to 4.2 V) from a USB connector supplying 5 V or (after negotiation) a higher voltage.

The higher voltage is used to transfer **more power** through the USB connection using a higher voltage (while keeping the same current), then using a DCDC buck converter to lower the voltage down to the voltage that the battery needs but with **more current** available so charging can go faster.

Fast charging cells in series brings extra challenges with it, each cell has to be monitored individually. As far as I know, QCC doesn't implement this.

Connecting chargers in series is **asking for trouble**, they're not designed for that. It will not work anyway as you need a dedicated 3S charger to charge cells in series. There is no way around that.

Comment: Which dedicated 3S charger do you recommend pls ?

Comment: We don't give product recommendations on this site.